# How can a JSR 330 dependency injector verify dependencies at build time?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I am looking at the JSR 330 (`javax.inject`) [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/package-summary.html) and am confused by the following sentence:

> Moreover, the injector can verify that all dependencies have been satisfied at *build time*.

How is this possible?* Which implementations support this?

*I am guessing there must be some code generation involved, but how does that code know that it is being compiled in order to generate the code necessary to statically verify that dependencies are met?

Comment: Interesting. Wondering if that's why my IDE (Netbeans) complains with `Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point` in the code editor. I'm curious how to resolve that. Looking around some (https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/packagingdeployment.html#beanarchive), I'm guessing that Netbeans is looking around for a bean archive (beans.xml) for beans that will satisfy the injection points.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Framework support jsr-330 and can be configured to weaving at compile time using the AspectJ compiler, it means that classes are modified at byte-code to introduce dependency injection during compile phase. By the fault spring performs weaving at runtime.
See [Does Spring AOP do compile time weaving or load time weaving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549371/does-spring-aop-do-compile-time-weaving-or-load-time-weaving)